# Add a CountIF to a SumProduct Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

In a previous question, [Scott](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott) gave me this great formula to sum all the sales from salespeople who saw an increase in sales from 2017 to 2018:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C9-B2:B9, --(C2:C9>B2:B9), --(B2:B9>0))
```

Now I need a formula that counts how many salespeople saw an increase in sales from 2017 to 2018.  I've fiddled around CountIF, but I'm still a novice with these advanced formulas, so I couldn't figure it out.

Here is sample data:

```
**A**---------------**B**--------------**C**---- 
**Salesman**----**2017 sales**---**2018 sales**
Todd Packer----------$14,547---------$15,487 
Michael Scott--------$26,487---------$24,491 
Dwight Schrutte------$19,124---------$19,458 
Phyllis Vance--------$13,891---------$14,551 
Stanley Hudson-------$17,541---------$17,541 
Jim Halpert----------$15,874---------$15,732 
Andy Bernard--------------$0----------$9,574 
Pam Beasley-----------$2,123--------------$0
```

Todd, Dwight and Phyllis each saw an increase in their sales, so the result I'm looking for is **3**.  I want to ignore Andy since he had no activity in 2017.

Comment: You will add a "helper column" in this case. The helper column will be =IF(2018 sales - 2017 sales >0,"x","") which will then place an x (or whatever character you want) if the sales increased. Then simply do a COUNTIF like you were looking at where the condition is "x" (or the character you chose)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a helper column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`:

To count the salespeople whose sales increased:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C9>B2:B9),--(B2:B9>0))
```

(this formulas will ignore salespeople whose initial results (`column B`) were `0`)

To count the ones whose sales decreased:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C9<B2:B9),--(C2:C9>0))
```

(this formulas will ignore salespeople whose final results (`column C`) were `0`)